# Update panel jQuery click event triggering twice

Tags: jquery, updatepanel, .net-4.5, bind

I have a update panel with a button and I'm binding a click event to that button using the following snippet:

```
var prm = Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance();
prm.add_endRequest(function ()
```

The problem is, I am seeing the click event is firing twice and it is not consistent. When I refresh the same page, issue is going off and on without any clue.

Another one info, I'm loading the entire control in the OnTick event of a timer.

Comment: Can you clarify? You're adding the click events within a timer, or?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy i don't get your question actually... but button click event is bounded after the Ontick of timer